# vs2017 error ado.net model wizard ErikEJ SqlCeToolbox

Tags: sqlite, model, ado.net, entity-framework-6, wizard

vs2017 v15.5.6
ado.net model wizard not working

my app.config

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>  
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

error:

> An error occured while connecting to the database. The database might be unavailable. an exception of type 'system.invalidcastexception' occurred. the error message is:system.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection cannot be cast to system.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection. Type A originates from 'system.data.sqlite, version=1.0.108.0, culture=neutral

Comment: Please copy the error to your question with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If the link of that image ever changes, the value of your question disappears, and it is not the [only reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9269043)

Comment: Error message "An error occured while connecting to the database. The database might be unavailable. an exception of type 'system.invalidcastexception' occurred. the error message is:system.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection cannot be cast to system.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection. Type A originates from 'system.data.sqlite, version=1.0.108.0, culture=neutral"

Answer (score 0):

So, I uninstall

```
System.Data.SQLite 1.0.109
System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.109
System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.109
System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.109

and install
System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.108
System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.108
System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.108
System.Data.SQLite 1.0.108
```

problem solved
Thanks for all